# Retrieve data using query from all WordPress pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem of query page. I want to query all pages but it's not working.
What have I done wrong? I don't know. Please help me.

```
public function my_get_all_page_types() {
    $page_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    $pages = $page_args;
    $page_list = [];
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $page_list[$page->ID] = $page->post_title;
    }

    return $page_list;
}
```

This is output:

```
$this->add_control( 'UA_page_list_select',
        [
            'label' => __( 'Page List Box', 'my-elementor' ),
            'type' => Controls_Manager::SELECT,
            'multiple' => false,
            'default' => [],
            'options' => $this->my_get_all_page_types(),
        ]
    );
```

This is my another way:

```
public function my_get_all_page_types() {
   $pages = get_pages(); 
   foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
      $option .= $page->post_title;
      echo $option;
   }
}
```

Comment: _"This is output"_ - That looks more like code. How are the two code blocks related? The method you posted is named `my_get_all_page_types()` while the other code block uses `UA_get_all_page_types()`? Are you calling the wrong method?

Comment: You try to call my_get_all_page_types starting with "my" with the following function $this->UA_get_all_page_types() starting with UA?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, i have fixed this but same problem . This is not working.

Comment: @Jayr , This is not working :(

Comment: If you want all wordpress page as a list for that you can try following.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/

Comment: Can you provide the full class code for us to check?

Comment: You're not actually fetching anything in your method. You're just creating an array with arguments, which you then iterate through and use the values (which you just created) as objects. This code should throw a bunch of errors.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, so what i need to do. please tel me :(

Comment: So, in your first method, you're not actually fetching anything. You're just creating an array. In your second method (after the update), you _do_ get all pages, but then creates one long string with all the titles, which you then return.  Use your first method, remove the `$post_args` array and just add: `$pages = get_pages();` (keep your foreach-loop) and see if that works better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing your query args into `wp_query` object. Just replace your above functions with follows -

```
public function my_get_all_page_types() {
    $page_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'numberposts' => -1,
    );
    $pages = get_posts($page_args);
    $page_list = [];
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $page_list[$page->ID] = $page->post_title;
    }

    return $page_list;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much . It's working fine :)